# Tkinter displaying button instead of Label

Tags: python, button, tkinter, label

I am creating a little app that will take in details from the user about a bank transaction and then display it in a table. 
I am currently using a CSV file to store the data and then when a new piece of data is put in, it will display that too.

I have a list of labels and then a button at the bottom of them to submit new entry. The problem I am getting is when the length of the table exceeds what it was to begin with there is a display error.

```
class accountant(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        master.title("Accountant")
        self.pack()
        self.numIncoming = 0
        self.numOutgoing = 0
        self.incoming = fs.fileStore("incoming", "csv")
        print("log: incoming.csv opened sucessfully")
        self.outgoing = fs.fileStore("outgoing", "csv")
        print("log: outgoing.csv opened sucessfully")
        self.setup()

    def setup(self):


        self.paint()
        self.incomingData()

        self.outgoingData()

        self.newEntryButtons()




    def paint(self): 
        tk.Label(self, width=45, text="incoming").grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=45)
        tk.Label(self, width=45, text="outgoing").grid(row=1, column=45, columnspan=45)

        tk.Label(self, width=15, text="Date").grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=15)
        tk.Label(self, width=15, text="Transaction Name").grid(row=2, column=15, columnspan=15)
        tk.Label(self, width=15, text="Amount").grid(row=2, column=30, columnspan=15)

        tk.Label(self, width=15, text="Date").grid(row=2, column=45, columnspan=15)
        tk.Label(self, width=15, text="Transaction Name").grid(row=2, column=60, columnspan=15)
        tk.Label(self, width=15, text="Amount").grid(row=2, column=75, columnspan=15)

    def incomingData(self):
        self.incoming.closeFile()
        self.incoming.openFile()

        i = 3
        for cell in self.incoming.reader:
        #cell[0] = Date, cell[1]= Transaction Name, cell[2] =amount
            tk.Label(self, width=15, text=cell[0]).grid(row=i, column=0, columnspan=15)
            tk.Label(self, width=15, text=cell[1]).grid(row=i, column=15, columnspan=15)
            tk.Label(self, width=15, text=cell[2]).grid(row=i, column=30, columnspan=15)
            i += 1

        self.numIncoming = i
        print("incoming:", self.numIncoming-3)  
        print("outgoing:", self.numOutgoing-3)


    def outgoingData(self):
        self.outgoing.closeFile()
        self.outgoing.openFile()
        i = 3
        for cell in self.outgoing.reader:
        #cell[0] = Date, cell[1]= Transaction Name, cell[2] =amount
            tk.Label(self, width=15, text=cell[0]).grid(row=i, column=45, columnspan=15)
            tk.Label(self, width=15, text=cell[1]).grid(row=i, column=60, columnspan=15)
            tk.Label(self, width=15, text=cell[2]).grid(row=i, column=75, columnspan=15)
            i += 1
        self.numOutgoing = i
        print("incoming:", self.numIncoming-3)
        print("outgoing:", self.numOutgoing-3, '\n\n')



    def newEntryButtons(self):
        if(self.numIncoming < self.numOutgoing):
            tk.Button(self, text="new incoming", width=45, command=lambda: self.newEntry(self.incoming)).grid(row=self.numOutgoing, column=0, columnspan=45)
            tk.Button(self, text="new outgoing", width=45, command=lambda: self.newEntry(self.outgoing)).grid(row=self.numOutgoing, column=45, columnspan=45)
        else:
            tk.Button(self, text="new incoming", width=45, command=lambda: self.newEntry(self.incoming)).grid(row=self.numIncoming, column=0, columnspan=45)
            tk.Button(self, text="new outgoing", width=45, command=lambda: self.newEntry(self.outgoing)).grid(row=self.numIncoming, column=45, columnspan=45)

    def newEntry(self, inFile):
        win = tk.Toplevel()

        self.newName = tk.StringVar()
        self.newDate = tk.StringVar()
        self.newAmount = tk.StringVar()


        tk.Label(win, width=5, text="Name:").grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=5)
        tk.Entry(win, textvariable=self.newName).grid(row=0, column=5, columnspan=5)

        tk.Label(win, width=5, text="date:").grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=5)
        tk.Entry(win, textvariable = self.newDate).grid(row=1, column=5, columnspan=5)

        tk.Label(win, width=5, text="amount: £").grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=5)
        tk.Entry(win, textvariable=self.newAmount).grid(row=2, column=5, columnspan=5)

        button = tk.Button(win, text="submit", width=5, command= lambda: self.submit(win, inFile))
        button.grid(row=5, column=5, columnspan=5)

    def submit(self, win, inFile):
        with open(inFile.file, 'a') as f:
            string= '\n'+self.newName.get() + ',' + self.newDate.get() + ',' + self.newAmount.get()
            f.write(string)
        if inFile.fileName == "incoming":
            self.numIncoming += 1
        #   print("incoming:", self.numIncoming-3)
        #   print("outgoing:", self.numOutgoing-3)
        else:
            self.numOutgoing += 1
            print("outgoing:", self.numOutgoing-3)
        win.destroy()
        self.setup()
```

filestore is just a class that basically opens the csv using 
`reader = csv.reader(open(file+'.'fileExt))` where file and fileExt are the parameters passed in.

Here is the image after a new entry. the bottom two buttons should stay as they are and the top two should be d    e    f  in the left column and just whitespace in the right column
[image: Image after new entry]

Comment: i think that you should create the buttons last and their .grid option should not have `row=` defined. That way, it will insert it in the first EMPTY row

Answer (score 1):

Replace self.pack() with self.grid(). To change a Label to Button you will, in addition, have to define a command function that executes when the Button is pressed, see the code below

```
bttn = tk.Button(self, text = "buttontitle",  command = self.do_function )
bttn.grid(row = 14, column = 4, sticky = W)


def do_function():
    print "HI"
```

Comment: I think that @Martyn's issue is from the `Label` being placed over the `Button` when the `outGoingData()` function is called, not switching between the two types.

Comment: Ok, one thing that is an issue with the code is that the OP is using self.pack() but then grid() in the paint() method. It would be easier to re-write the code with pack() with weights to create some of the buttons dynamically. Another thing is in the newEntryButtons(self) where the if else statement is saying to do the exact same thing no matter if(self.numIncoming < self.numOutgoing) or not.

Comment: @user1749431 The reason for the if else statement is in the .grid(row="") bit. If the numIncoming < numOutgoing it is placed 1 row below the last outgoing, else it is placed one row below the last incoming. It may not be the right way to do it but thats what its for =D I will try using pack() .

Comment: If you change all buttons to pack() then you can do this with if(self.numIncoming < self.numOutgoing) self.button1 = tk.Text(self, width = 65, height = 25, wrap = WORD) self.buttn1.pack(side=TOP) else self.button2 = tk.Text(self, width = 65, height = 25, wrap = WORD) self.buttn2.pack(side=BOTTOM).